Eigenvalues of Laplace-Beltrami operator plus a smooth function on compact Riemannian manifold

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact, smooth Riemannian manifold. The Schrödinger
flow on $(M,g)$ associates to an initial datum $u_0\in L^2(M)$ the
solution $u(t,\cdot)$ to the Schrödinger equation: \begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned} & i\partial_t u(t,x)=-\Delta_x u(t,x), \quad
 (t,x)\in \mathbb{R}\times M \\ &u|_{t=0}=u_0. \end{aligned}\right.
 \end{equation} Above, $\Delta_x$ denotes the Laplace-Beltrami operator
corresponding to $(M,g)$. Since $M$ is compact, the spectrum of
$-\Delta_x$ consists of eigenvalues $0=\lambda_0<\lambda_1\leq
 \lambda_2\dots$ that tend to infinity. We shall denote by
$(\psi_{\lambda_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ an orthonormal basis of $L^2(M)$
consisting of eigenfunctions $-\Delta_x \psi_{\lambda_n}=\lambda_n
 \psi_{\lambda_n}$. One has $u(t,\cdot)=e^{it\Delta_x} u_0$ and the
following representation holds: $$ e^{it\Delta_x}
 u_0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} e^{-i\lambda_n t} \hat u_0(\lambda_n)
 \psi_{\lambda_n},\quad \text{provided } u_0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \hat
 u_0 (\lambda_n) \psi_{\lambda_n}. $$

It is my first time to read the paper related to Schrödinger equation on compact Riemannian manifold. I wonder why the statement above holds or which book introduced related results? Furthermore, when $M$ is a flat 2-torus $\mathbb{T}^2$, what is the difference between the eigenvalue of $-\Delta_x$ and $-\Delta_x+V(x)$, where $V\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$?
Thanks in advance!

The flat torus in $\mathbb R^n$ with perodic potentials is the standard model of electron theory in a lattice. By Blochs theroeom the Schrödinger spectrum in a periodic potential with with periodic boundary conditions in a large cube splits into bands of periodic functions times an exponential, carrying the so called lattice-momentum $\psi_{n,k}(\vec x)) \ = \ u_{n,k}(x) \ e^{i k x}$.  The range of the $k$-vector is constrained to a cell in the inverse lattice by Fourier transform.
